# Add image over a block

Tags: html, css, image

I'm using this mini pricing table: http://codepen.io/joejoinerr/pen/CJAkK

How can I put an image on top of it? Like this:

[image]

Code of the pricing table also here:

HTML:

```
<div class="pricing">
  <div class="price-option price-option--low">
    <div class="price-option__detail">
      <span class="price-option__cost">$0</span>
      <span class="price-option__type">Freeuser</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="price-option__purchase">Get</a>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  background: #454c4f;
  font: 1em/1.5 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
.pricing {
  @include translate(-49%, -49.1%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 310px;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.price-option {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.3125em;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.price-option:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

.pricing:hover .price-option { opacity: 0.6; }
.pricing:hover .price-option:hover { opacity: 1; }

.price-option__detail {
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.price-option--low .price-option__detail  { border-radius: .25em 0 0 0; }
.price-option--mid .price-option__detail  { padding: 2.3em 0; border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0; }
.price-option--high .price-option__detail { border-radius: 0 .25em 0 0; }

.price-option__cost,
.price-option__type {
  display: block;
}
.price-option__cost {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #383838;
}   
.price-option__type {
  font-size: .7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #909090;
}    
.price-option__purchase {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .6em;
  font-size: .875em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}    
.price-option--low .price-option__purchase  { background: #a7d155; border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em; }
.price-option--mid .price-option__purchase  { background: #eada42; border-radius: 0 0 .25em .25em; }
.price-option--high .price-option__purchase { background: #e54e4b; border-radius: 0 0 .25em 0; }   
.price-option__purchase:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Add the image before pricing div wrapper and then position it relatively down as much as you need?

Comment: Add `:before` :pseudo-element. ----> Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/QwyZbe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use pseudo-element `:before`:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  background: #454c4f;
  font: 1em/1.5'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
.pricing {
  @include translate(-49%, -49.1%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 310px;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.price-option {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.25em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.3125em;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.price-option:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.price-option:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.pricing:hover .price-option {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.pricing:hover .price-option:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.price-option__detail {
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.price-option--low .price-option__detail {
  border-radius: .25em 0 0 0;
}
.price-option--mid .price-option__detail {
  padding: 2.3em 0;
  border-radius: .25em .25em 0 0;
}
.price-option--high .price-option__detail {
  border-radius: 0 .25em 0 0;
}
.price-option__cost,
.price-option__type {
  display: block;
}
.price-option__cost {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #383838;
}
.price-option__type {
  font-size: .7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #909090;
}
.price-option__purchase {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .6em;
  font-size: .875em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.price-option--low .price-option__purchase {
  background: #a7d155;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.price-option--mid .price-option__purchase {
  background: #eada42;
  border-radius: 0 0 .25em .25em;
}
.price-option--high .price-option__purchase {
  background: #e54e4b;
  border-radius: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
.price-option__purchase:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.price-option--low .price-option__purchase:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #a7d155;
}
.price-option--mid .price-option__purchase:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #eada42;
}
.price-option--high .price-option__purchase:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #e54e4b;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing">
  <div class="price-option price-option--low">
    <div class="price-option__detail">
      <span class="price-option__cost">$0</span>
      <span class="price-option__type">Freeuser</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="price-option__purchase">Get</a>
  </div>
  <div class="price-option price-option--mid">
    <div class="price-option__detail">
      <span class="price-option__cost">$20</span>
      <span class="price-option__type">Poweruser</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="price-option__purchase">Buy</a>
  </div>
  <div class="price-option price-option--high">
    <div class="price-option__detail">
      <span class="price-option__cost">$40</span>
      <span class="price-option__type">Superuser</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="price-option__purchase">Buy</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an image to the container and position it absolutely, for example

```
<div class="price-option price-option--mid">
    <img class="top_image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/casino/96/Banana-icon.png"/>
    <div class="price-option__detail">
      <span class="price-option__cost">$20</span>
      <span class="price-option__type">Poweruser</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="price-option__purchase">Buy</a>
</div>

.top_image {
     position:absolute;
     top:-60px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPwJXa